# How to add stereo,treble options in audio equalizer?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, audio, equalizer

I am trying to a small audio songs equalizer. I want to add in it options of treble,stereo like it is in Poweramp player.

[image: Image of poweramp music player]

I implemented equlizer with 5 bands successfully like this:-

```
public class FragmentEqualizer extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);

        equalizer = new EQ(getActivity(), new Equalizer(0,com.androidhive.musicplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.mp.getAudioSessionId()));
       for(Bar bar : eqBars)
            bar.setActiveEQ();
       maximum= EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevelRange()[1];
       minimum= EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevelRange()[0];
    }


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


                   lvforprest.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                                btnformenu.setText(gtuforpresets.get(position).gtumcaFirstName);
                                if(position!=0 && position <=10)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                 EQ.getEqualizer().usePreset((short) (position-1));
                          EQ.getEqualizer().setBandLevel((short)0,  EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 0));
                          EQ.getEqualizer().setBandLevel((short)1,  EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 1));
                          EQ.getEqualizer().setBandLevel((short)2, EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 2));
                          EQ.getEqualizer().setBandLevel((short)3,  EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 3));
                          EQ.getEqualizer().setBandLevel((short)4,  EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 4));

                          eqBars.get(0).setEQPosition(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 0));
                          eqBars.get(1).setEQPosition(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 1));
                          eqBars.get(2).setEQPosition(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 2));
                          eqBars.get(3).setEQPosition(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 3));
                          eqBars.get(4).setEQPosition(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 4));
                          seekbar1katop.setText(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 0)+"mB");
                          seekbar2katop.setText(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 1)+"mB");
                          seekbar3katop.setText(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 2)+"mB");
                          seekbar4katop.setText(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 3)+"mB");
                          seekbar5katop.setText(EQ.getEqualizer().getBandLevel((short) 4)+"mB");


                                 }
                                    catch(IllegalStateException e)
                                    {
                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Unable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
                                {
                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Unable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                    catch(UnsupportedOperationException e)
                                    {
                                      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Unable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }

                            //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You Clicked : " + mEqualizer.getEnabled(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }
                        });

}
}
```

Above code is just a short brief of my equalizer code.it wont work just as a example i posted here .
.

I too want to add treble, stereo, mono effects in my equalizer.

I already implemented bass boost like this:

```
public static void setBassBoost(BassBoost bassBoost, int percent) {
        try{
            bassBoost.setStrength((short) ((short) 1000 / 100 * percent));
            bassBoost.setEnabled(true);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    public static void setBassBoostOff(BassBoost bassBoost) {
        bassBoost.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

I used an inbulilt class for bass boost.

How can I add treble and stereo/mono effects to my app?

Comment: To manipulate treble and bass, use the [Equalizer effect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) and change the band levels. To get stereo widening, use the [Virtualizer effect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Virtualizer.html). I'm not sure what the "mono effect" is supposed to do.

Comment: give me a this demo or this module. bcz i have also work costume visulizer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**In order to change the bass, mid, treble there's no need to use the `AudioTrack`** object (even because with this object you could only playback non-compressed PCM data).

You just need to adjust the proper frequency bands level using your [`Equalizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) object. To get the number of available bands, just call:

```
myEqualizer.getNumberOfBands()
```

Considering the number of available bands, you can now set the level for each band using the following method:

```
myEqualizer.setBandLevel(band, level);
```

where:

> **band**: frequency band that will have the new gain. The numbering of the
>   bands starts from 0 and ends at (number of bands - 1).
>
> **level**:    new gain
>   in millibels that will be set to the given band. getBandLevelRange()
>   will define the maximum and minimum values.

The meaning of each bands, from left to right, is summarized in the following image:

[image: bands meaning]

**UPDATE**

To implement a trivial **balance** effect, just differentiate the left/right volume on your player (`MediaPlayer`, `SoundPool`,...):

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(left, right)
```

---

To obtain a **mono** effect you can consider using a [Virtualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Virtualizer.html), which provides a stereo widening effect. You can set the strength of the virtualization effect using the method:

```
virtualizer.setStrength(1000); //range is [0..1000]
```

You need to read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Virtualizer.html#canVirtualize(int,%20int)) carefully in order to check if the current configuration of your virtualizer is really supported by the underlying system.

---

Anyway, this is not a real mono output and I think you won't be able to obtain a mono ouput on stereo speaker without using low level API such as `AudioTrack` (*actually Poweramp relies on native JNI libraries for its audio pipeline*). 
If you want to use an `AudioTrack` for playback you need to consider that it only supports PCM data (WAV) as input: this means you won't be able to play compressed audio file (like MP3, flac, ...) directly since you need to manually decode the compressed audio file first.

```
[Compressed File (MP3)] ===> decode() ===> [PCM data] ===> customEffect() ===> AudioTrack playback()
```

Thus, in order to **play a compressed audio using and AudioTrack** (and eventually create a custom effect) the following steps are required:

1. decode the compressed file using a [decoder](https://github.com/thasmin/android-mp3decoders) (**NO PUBLIC SYSTEM API available for this, you need to do it manually!!!**).
2. if necessary, transform uncompressed data in a [PCM format which is compatible with AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat.html#ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
3. (eventually) apply your transformation on the PCM data stream (e.g. you can merge both L/R channels and create a mono effect)
4. [play the PCM stream using an AudioTrack](http://jongladwin.blogspot.it/2010/03/android-play-pcmwav-audio-buffer-using.html)

I suggest you to skip this effect ;)

---

Regarding the **bass-boost** effect, you need to check if your current configuration is supported by the the running device (like the virtualizer). Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30162020/2760919) for more info on this.

Comment: @developer *Mid* stands for *midrange frequencies*

Comment: i tried doing this.but it is not working as per in poweramp player.....i cannt get any signifcant change in audio of song

Comment: Ad wat about stereo and mono ?

Comment: @developer I've updated my answer, that's all I know :)

Comment: @developer tell us your doubts, I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: Yes. The bass boost is just...a boost :-)