# How to set various sound effect treble,echo in android?

Tags: java, android, api, audio, equalizer

I am trying to set sound effect treble and echo for my audio player project in android but i am not getting how to do it.

I already searched google a lot and asked a question also related to it, but that thing not working now.

Any help will be appreciated well...............
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: reason of downvote plz

Comment: This topic as already been discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969236/how-to-add-stereo-treble-options-in-audio-equalizer

Comment: @bonnyz just suggest me how to add treble....thats it i want now ...please tell :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [BassBoost](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/audiofx/BassBoost.html) but no TrebleBoost already worked out in Android.

Instead you will nedd to instantiate an [Equalizer](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) object. Query the object for the amount of frequency bands (usually they're 5) and use [setBandLevel](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html#setBandLevel%28short,%20short%29) to boost the higher bands.

Comment: It will work as treble as long as you only boost the higher bands

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the various sound effects in your audio player you can take reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969236/how-to-add-stereo-treble-options-in-audio-equalizer) . It is the best solution i found for your problem. Hope it helps !!