# Assigning Equalizer to a single channel

Tags: android, audio, channel, equalizer

Since I have some sort of hearing loss, affecting different frequencies on my ear, I was planning to develop an app that would have an equalizer on the two different channels (stereio) music usually plays on.

However, I haven't been able to do do that.
What usually is done is to assign the equalizer object to a session id like so:

```
mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, audioSessionId1);
```

However, it affects both (or all) channels.
Any way out of it?

And no, channel balance/panning which is available on most of players is not enough for my ocd.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to read about Equalizer,BassBoost and Virtualizer

See [**this Sample**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.java)

And also have a look at my Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30162020/3496570)  And a nice explanation [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33022774/3496570)